# Firestore + Nested Promise and ForEach + React-Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, redux, google-cloud-firestore

Alright so I kinda got stuck doing nested queries with `firestore` because of `ForEach and nested Promise returns`. From all the previous posts on `stackoverflow` I understood quite a bit about promises and then nesting them inside ForEach. However, I couldnt find a solution where I nest promise inside forEach which then has another forEach inside it.

I do understand that I have to use `Promise.all` to make the root forEach wait but how to tell it to wait until the `.then()` also returns something?

```
firebase.firestore().collection("Feeds").get().then(feedsSnapshot => {
            let promiseArray = [], anotherPromiseArray = [];
            feedsSnapshot.forEach(function (feed) {
                let promise = checkifILikedTheFeed(feed).then(like => {
                    return like;
                }).then(like => {
                    let anotherPromise = firebase.firestore().collection("Feeds").doc(feed.id).collection("Likes").get()
                        .then(likesSnapshot => {
                            if(likesSnapshot.empty){
                                return {
                                    // return myData
                                };
                            } else {
                                let countLikes = 0;
                                likesSnapshot.forEach(likeDoc => {
                                    if(likeDoc.data().isLike){
                                        countLikes++;
                                    }
                                });
                                return {
                                    //myData + countLikes
                                };
                            }
                        });
                    anotherPromiseArray.push(anotherPromise);
                //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                 // I thought this would work, sadly doesnt.
                });
                promiseArray.push(promise);
            });
            return Promise.all([promiseArray,anotherPromiseArray]);
        }).then(feeds => {
            console.log(feeds);
        //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        //  returns [[undefined],[undefined]]
            dispatch({
                type: 'RETRIEVE_FEEDS',
                payload: feeds,
            });
        });
```